# Chip sync error while updating ATfirmware in esp8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I find trouble updating my firmware with esp8266 with following error message.

[espDownloader.py][line:351][ERROR]: Chip sync error: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
[2019-06-04 07:53:16,009][ESP8266Loader_spi[1]][espDownloader.py][line:439][ERROR]: ESP8266 Chip sync error esp_sync_blocking.

I am unable to resolve even after a number of attempts.
Please help me resolve my issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: is the module in flashing mode, by pulling io 0 LOW at boot?

Comment: Yes m putting it in flash mode

Comment: does the original firmware answer over that port, cable and adapter?

Comment: my original firmware provides Garbage data and displays ready command, but  it doesn't answers any AT command.

Comment: read the 'garbage; at 74880 baud. it is the boot log. (some part will be always garbage or Chinese) send AT command at 115200 baud with both line ends set

Comment: thank you for your help, there was some problem with my chip. I bought an another one and it's working fine.